# VB.NET to C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, vb.net-to-c#

I have the following LINQ

```
            Dim z = (From d In db.GPSdevice
                     Where d.CompanyId = currentuser.CompanyId And d.Type = "Truck" Or d.Type = "Trailer"
                     Order By d.ListOrder Descending
                     Group d By d.Driver Into g = Group
                     Select g.FirstOrDefault())
```

I try to convert it to c#

```
        var z = db.GPSdevices
            .Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyID && p.Type == "Truck" || p.Type == "Trailer") 
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.ListOrder)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Driver)
            .Select(g => new { Group = g });
```

but not sure, how to convert Select g.FirstOrDefault()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `g.FirstOrDefault()` in your `Select`

```
    var z = db.GPSdevices
        .Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyID && p.Type == "Truck" || p.Type == "Trailer") 
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.ListOrder)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Driver)
        .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [query syntax in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) too, no need to rewrite using the extension methods directly:

```
var z = (from d In db.GPSdevice
        where (d.CompanyId == currentuser.CompanyId) && (d.Type == "Truck") || (d.Type == "Trailer")
        orderby d.ListOrder descending
        group d by d.Driver into g = group
        select g.FirstOrDefault())
```